# How to break information on an event for the logging

Tags: python, logging

I have been using the logging module in Python for a while. My doubt is not so much a technical one, but that I am not sure of the best practices with the messages. The issue is that sometimes an event happens and I want to dump information about it in the log, but a lot of information. I can build a single long string, and use it in an log.info() command. That is alright, except for the fact that the result is hardly human-readable. Introducing the character '\n' in the string indeed breaks the message into separate lines in the log file, but left-justified, it looks ugly because in the beginning of the logging formatter I am writing the date/time, user, etc.

On the other hand I can split the message into different calls to log.info(), but that makes it look as if they were different events.

EDIT: Additional information.

If I do different log calls, it looks like

```
2012-10-01 11:55:00,674 - SQLBOLPVWBA01 - WARNING   | ---------- Warning 001: a test was not passed ----------
2012-10-01 11:55:00,694 - SQLBOLPVWBA01 - WARNING   | File: \\b1snnasries01.SAN.CORP\D_8525_50_01\ValidacionModelos\Usuarios\Equity\testsValidationLibrary\XMLs\barrierMC\barrierMCbasket_0002_Q011388.xml
2012-10-01 11:55:00,704 - SQLBOLPVWBA01 - WARNING   | Parametrization: configMatlabMC8192.m
2012-10-01 11:55:00,732 - SQLBOLPVWBA01 - WARNING   | Expected: {'premium': 0.1302634916172996, 'stdErr': 0.0016369990559715}
2012-10-01 11:55:00,765 - SQLBOLPVWBA01 - WARNING   | Calculated: {'premium': 0.13526349161729959, 'stdErr': 0.0016369990559715229}
```

What is the usual/best practice here?

I think I would like something like

```
2012-10-01 11:55:00,674 - SQLBOLPVWBA01 - WARNING  | ---------- Warning 001: a test was not passed ----------
                                                   | File: \\b1snnasries01.SAN.CORP\D_8525_50_01\ValidacionModelos\Usuarios\Equity\testsValidationLibrary\XMLs\barrierMC\barrierMCbasket_0002_Q011388.xml
                                                   | Parametrization: configMatlabMC8192.m
                                                   | Expected: {'premium': 0.1302634916172996, 'stdErr': 0.0016369990559715}
                                                   | Calculated: {'premium': 0.13526349161729959, 'stdErr': 0.0016369990559715229}
```

Comment: please place sample of ur data and expected output atleast . we can solve

Comment: Handle long string before call log.info(), such as: replace '\n' to ''.

Comment: @SundarNataraj: You are right, information added.

Comment: there is a problem here each line in ur input is a log entry. i think v cannot change that while logger is writter. later u can change it using file operation. is that u want?

Comment: @SundarNataraj: I would hate to have to postprocess log files, specially because you never know when more info is dumped, if that is what you are suggesting. I guess I would rather modify the behaviour of the logging info(), warning() methods, so that '\n' is replaced by spaces and '\n', I would call them only once and the result would be aligned. But I thought maybe there is a simpler solution (or a feature of logging I do not know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log the messages using `\n` to separate the lines, as you've already considered, then write a custom `Formatter` subclass which splits the message into separate lines, inserts the appropriate whitespace prefix for the subsequent lines and joins them back together again.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely do that.